# Power consumption on Dell XPS 15 9560 + Ubuntu 17.04 (dualboot)

Tags: dell, power-management, battery, powertop, tlp

I've installed Ubuntu (kernel 4.10.0-26-generic) on my Dell XPS 15 and so far everything is good. I made some low-hanging power consumption optimizations:

- Disabled discrete Nvidia GPU
- Installed TLP
- Installed powertop and set all parameters to "Good"
- Disabled touchscreen

Now in idle my power consumption, according to powertop, is around 7-10w.

But still, when I'm doing my usual work (running 1-2 Webstorm instances, Webpack dev server, browser with multiple tabs, wifi, sometimes music, brightness <50%), I'm not quite happy with battery life. Today I went from 100% to 40% in 2:30 hours.

I ran a 30 minutes powertop monitoring while doing my usual work, and it looks quite strange, it seems like the Intel GPU consumes too much power, but I'm not sure.

These are top 3 power consumers according to the powertop report:

```
Usage | Events/s | Category | Description | PW Estimate  
5676% | 33,5 | kWork | intel_mmio_flip_work_func | 170 W  
0,0% | 7,7 | Process | /opt/google/chrome/chrome | 50.9 mW  
1,3% | 0,00 | Timer | process_timeout | 38.7 mW
```

And it doesn't make any sense, I mean, 170W? Really?

Full report can be seen [here](http://trainer-creeks-62202.bitballoon.com/)

What can I do to further optimize the power consumption?

Thanks.

Comment: `5676%` usage? I suspect that `powertop` is confused or lying to you.